# laravel 5.1 eloquent query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I got a query that works fine in PMA and I'm trying to convert it to Eloquent, but I must be missing something.
Here the SQL query:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM ppr__child_absence t1 
LEFT JOIN ppr__children t3 ON t3.idcode=t1.child_idcode 
WHERE t1.id = (SELECT t2.id FROM ppr__child_absence t2 
    WHERE t2.child_idcode = t1.child_idcode 
    ORDER BY t2.id DESC LIMIT 1) 
AND t3.deleted_at IS NULL 
AND $input BETWEEN start AND stop;
```

and hes is my eloquent query:

```
$input = Request::all();
$pprs =
    DB::table('ppr__child_absence')
    ->join('ppr__children', function($join) {
        $join->on('ppr__children.idcode', '=', 'ppr_children_absence.child_idcode')
            ->where('ppr__child_absence.child_idcode', '=', DB::raw('SELECT t2.id FROM ppr__child_absence t2
              WHERE t2.child_idcode = ppr__child_absence.child_idcode
              ORDER BY t2.id DESC LIMIT 1'));})
            ->whereNull('ppr__children.deleted_at')
            ->whereBetween($input, array('ppr_children_absence.start','ppr_children_absence.stop'))->get();
```

I'm keep getting error:
ErrorException in Grammar.php line 58:
strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.

Can anyone here lead me to right direction?
Basically user has 1 date input with datepicker and submit button to get result according to the date chosen.

working query here with out errors but no results

```
$input = Request::all();
    $pprs = DB::table('ppr__child_absence')
            ->select('ppr__child_absence.*')
            ->join('ppr__children', function($join) {
            $join->on('ppr__children.idcode', '=', 'ppr__child_absence.child_idcode')
                ->where('ppr__child_absence.id', '=', DB::raw('SELECT t2.id FROM ppr__child_absence t2
                  WHERE t2.child_idcode = ppr__child_absence.child_idcode
                  ORDER BY t2.id DESC LIMIT 1'));})
                ->whereNull('ppr__children.deleted_at')
                ->where('ppr__child_absence.start', '<', $input['ppr_day'])
                ->where('ppr__child_absence.stop', '>', $input['ppr_day'])->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

`$input = Request::all();` stores all the input fields in an array.

You are using `->whereBetween($input,...)` and the first parameter of `whereBetween()` is expected to be a string (the name of the table column) but you are passing an array.

You didn't give details about the input. Assuming the input contains a field called 'field', the you should use `->whereBetween($input['field'],...)` instead

Comment: thanks! I did miss that but there is also something else. I getting error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '2015-09-26' in 'where clause'. it tries to find a column and does not recognize it is a date. Even when its declared in model file. $input field field name would be 'ppr_day' .

Comment: also added a line ->select('ppr__child_absence.*') after  DB::table('ppr__child_absence')

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to want is not what the `whereBetween` method offers. When using `whereBetween` the logic is that you want a given column value to be between two input values. The example in the [Laravel Query Builder Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses) is chosen well:

```
// the column 'votes' value should be between 1 and 100
$users = DB::table('users')->whereBetween('votes', [1, 100]);
```

What you seem to want is to make sure an input value is between two different column values. You can do that by having two separate conditions:

```
->where('ppr_children_absence.start', '<', $input['value'])
->where('ppr_children_absence.stop', '>', $input['value'])
```

This will make sure that `$input['value'])` is between the `start` and `stop` column values.

Comment: Thanks! That + little typo fixes did the trick. I looks like it to work, gives no errors but result is 0 even tho i got some data in database.

Comment: query dump gave me this
`
"SELECT `ppr__child_absence`.* from `ppr__child_absence`   
inner join `ppr__children` on `ppr__children`.`idcode` = 
`ppr__child_absence`.`child_idcode` 

  and `ppr__child_absence`.`id` = ? 

  where `ppr__children`.`deleted_at` is null 

  and `ppr__child_absence`.`start` &lt; ? and 
`ppr__child_absence`.`stop` &gt; ?"
`
looks like the raw query is not executing or what? why is it "?" ?

Comment: Try using `whereRaw` instead of `where`, like so `->whereRaw('t1.id = (SELECT t2.id FROM ppr__child_absence t2 WHERE t2.child_idcode = t1.child_idcode ORDER BY t2.id DESC LIMIT 1)')`.

Comment: looked promising but gives an error
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::whereRaw()`
I tried even cutting the raw out by changing it to =
`DB::table('ppr__child_absence AS t2')
                            ->select('t2.id')
                            ->where('t2.child_idcode', '=', 't1.child_idcode')
                            ->orderBy('t2.id', 'desc')
                            ->limit(1)
                            ->get()`
but with no luck unfortunately!